# How to implement Authorize.NET Hosted Payments iFrame & Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cross-domain, authorize.net

I found the official documentation and the github example provided by Authorize.NET to be a terribly confusing mess of stuff you don't need. This post is a summary of the last few hours work hoping it may help others.

This guide assumes you don't want the receipt page and you want to automatically move the user forward on successful payment.

Comment: i have set all this up as you descibe with mostly success. The issue we face is with mobile users on ios using Chrome AND Safari having to "approve" popups to proceed, mostly due to apple security settings. Have you had to solve this? Do you have advice?

Answer (score 13):

The site back-end is Laravel (PHP) but there's little in here that's Laravel specific.

First thing to do is add the Authorize.NET SDK:

```
composer require authorizenet/authorizenet
```

I then setup a hosted payments repository that accepts the order but you could do this however you like, this returns the hosted form token to a controller ready to pass to the view.

```
<?php

namespace ShopApp\Repositories;
use ShopApp\Models\Order;
use ShopApp\Repositories\Contracts\hostedPaymentRepositoryContract;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType;
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType;
use net\authorize\api\controller\GetHostedPaymentPageController;
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1\GetHostedPaymentPageRequest;
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1\SettingType;
use net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment;
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CustomerAddressType;
use ShopApp\Models\Address;

/**
 * Class hostedPaymentRepository
 * @package ShopApp\Repositories
 * @todo - Implement methods to talk to Authorize.NET and show form.
 */

class hostedPaymentRepository implements hostedPaymentRepositoryContract
{

    public $response; //what did we get back?
    public $paymentFormToken;

    public function getHostedFormToken(Order $order){

        $payment_amount = null;

        foreach($order->items as $order_item){

            $payment_amount += $order_item->price;

        }

        $billing_address = Address::findOrFail($order->billing_address_id);

        // Common setup for API credentials
        $merchantAuthentication = new MerchantAuthenticationType();
        $merchantAuthentication->setName(Config::get('yoursite.payment_providers.authorize_dot_net.MERCHANT_LOGIN_ID'));
        $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(Config::get('yoursite.payment_providers.authorize_dot_net.MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_KEY'));

        //create a transaction
        $transactionRequestType = new TransactionRequestType();
        $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");
        $transactionRequestType->setAmount($payment_amount);

        // Create the Bill To info
        $billto = new CustomerAddressType();
        $billto->setFirstName($order->billing_first_name);
        $billto->setLastName($order->billing_last_name);
        $billto->setAddress($billing_address->address_1);
        $billto->setCity($billing_address->city);
        $billto->setState($billing_address->state);
        $billto->setZip($billing_address->zip);
        $billto->setCountry($billing_address->country);

        if(!is_null($order->phone)){

            $billto->setPhoneNumber($order->phone);

        }

        //@todo - implement user stuff and get email
        //$billto->setEmail("changethis@later.com");

        $transactionRequestType->setBillTo($billto);

        // Set Hosted Form options
        $setting1 = new SettingType();
        $setting1->setSettingName("hostedPaymentButtonOptions");
        $setting1->setSettingValue("{\"text\": \"Pay Now\"}");

        $setting2 = new SettingType();
        $setting2->setSettingName("hostedPaymentOrderOptions");
        $setting2->setSettingValue("{\"show\": false}");

        $setting3 = new SettingType();
        $setting3->setSettingName("hostedPaymentReturnOptions");
        $setting3->setSettingValue("{\"showReceipt\" : false }");

        $setting4 = new SettingType();
        $setting4->setSettingName("hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl");
        $setting4->setSettingValue("{\"url\": \"https://yoursite.local/checkout/payment/response\"}");


        // Build transaction request
        $request = new GetHostedPaymentPageRequest();
        $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
        $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);

        $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting1);
        $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting2);
        $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting3);
        $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting4);

        //execute request
        $controller = new GetHostedPaymentPageController($request);
        $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);

        if (($response == null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() != "Ok") )
        {
            return false;
        }

        return $response->getToken();
    }

}
```

Note that I have set showReceipt to false and I have offered another setting called hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl. Do not forget the hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl otherwise you will get the reciept page regardless of setting showReceipt to false.

The hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl MUST be on the same domain as your payment page and on the same port.

Then in your view you need to add the iFrame (mine just sits in the page, i didn't bother with the lightbox:

```
<div id="iframe_holder" class="center-block" style="width:90%;max-width: 1000px" data-mediator="payment-form-loader">
    <iframe id="load_payment" class="embed-responsive-item" name="load_payment" width="750" height="900" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    </iframe>

    <form id="send_hptoken" action="https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment" method="post" target="load_payment">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $hosted_payment_form_token }}" />
    </form>

</div>
```

In the same view you need to load at least the following javascript (im using jQuery and have only half implemented the transactResponse method, but you get the idea):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.CommunicationHandler = {};

    function parseQueryString(str) {
        var vars = [];
        var arr = str.split('&');
        var pair;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            pair = arr[i].split('=');
            vars[pair[0]] = unescape(pair[1]);
        }
        return vars;
    }

    window.CommunicationHandler.onReceiveCommunication = function (argument) {

        console.log('communication handler enter');

        var params = parseQueryString(argument.qstr)

        switch(params['action']){
            case "resizeWindow"     :

                console.log('resize'); break;

            case "successfulSave"   :

                console.log('save'); break;

            case "cancel"           :

                console.log('cancel'); break;

            case "transactResponse" :

                sessionStorage.removeItem("HPTokenTime");

                console.log('transaction complete');

                var transResponse = JSON.parse(params['response']);

                window.location.href = '/checkout/complete';

        }
    }

    //send the token
    $('#send_hptoken').submit();


});
```

The above code adds a function to handle the message that comes back from the iFrame Communicator (next step) and also submits the payment form token to get and load the actual payment form.

Next we need to setup an 'iframe communicator' This is basically just a way for Authorize.NET to get around the [same-domain origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

To do this, create a new route and a view that just returns a simple HTML page (or a blade template, but it should have no content other than the scripts).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>IFrame Communicator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function callParentFunction(str) {

        if (str && str.length > 0 && window.parent.parent
            && window.parent.parent.CommunicationHandler && window.parent.parent.CommunicationHandler.onReceiveCommunication) {

            var referrer = document.referrer;
            window.parent.parent.CommunicationHandler.onReceiveCommunication({qstr : str , parent : referrer});

        }

    }

    function receiveMessage(event) {

        if (event && event.data) {
            callParentFunction(event.data);
        }

    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {

        window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

    } else if (window.attachEvent) {

        window.attachEvent("onmessage", receiveMessage);

    }

    if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash.length > 1) {

        callParentFunction(window.location.hash.substring(1));

    }

</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

The key part here is the window.parent.parent

Authorize.NET grabs your hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl that you gave it in the beginning and embeds this within another iFrame, inside their own payment iFrame. Which is why it's window.parent.parent.

Your hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl script then can pass the payment response to your payment page and you can edit the functions above to do what you like after that.

Hope that helps someone.

Authorize.NET is seriously lacking examples and their docs are lightweight at best. The 'catch-all' example that has you sifting through loads of code you don't need is just plain lazy.

Their API doc isn't bad though, they just need decent examples...

Comment: You are so right with your final comment. The examples try to explain too many concepts in one example. They just need to break it up into a few defined task examples. Regardless, your answer is great! I was running into the same issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this complete working example! Got it working on my application in a straightforward manner. Clear code and good explanation.

Comment: Their documentation SUCKS.  I have been sifting through the docs for days trying to figure out how to do some of the most basic stuff.  For instance, using the PHP SDK, how do you add the profile/customerProfileId to a getHostedPaymentPageRequest?  The method in the docs show:  * profile, ** customerProfileId - so you would think it would be `$profileType = new AnetAPI\ProfileType() ;` - but nope, `ProfileType` does not exist.

Comment: Is it normal to only be getting `resize` events? I feel like I should be getting success/failure methods, but all I ever get is `resize`. Except, when I click the Continue button, I get a `action=cancel` event. (???)