# iFrameCommunicator not receiving "'cancel" event

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, authorize.net

I'm implementing Authorize.net's ["Accept Hosted" iframe method](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/accept_hosted.html#Transaction_Response) for submitting online payments. I want to embed the Authorize.net checkout form in an iframe (or lightbox) and then redirect my page (or close the iframe/lightbox) when the transaction is complete or is cancelled.

As I understand it, the Authorize.net page embedded in the iframe will itself embed another iframe, used to communicate from the iframe back to my page without running into cross-domain problems.

I see Authorize.net's checkout form in my iframe and the nested iframe with my "communicator" page. However, the communicator doesn't seem to respond to the "cancel" button event. It will respond to the event if I pass a `cancelUrl` in the `hostedPaymentReturnOptions` setting, but then the iframe redirects upon clicking the cancel button. I don't want the iframe to redirect, I want my *parent page* to redirect (or close the iframe/lightbox).

**Using this setting:**

```php
$setting->setSettingName("hostedPaymentReturnOptions");
$setting->setSettingValue('{"showReceipt":false}');
```

... the communicator iframe is loaded and I see an event to resize the window:

> action=resizeWindow&width=1802&height=572

... but clicking the "cancel" button doesn't seem to fire any event.

**Using this setting:**

```php
$setting->setSettingName("hostedPaymentReturnOptions");
$setting->setSettingValue('{"showReceipt":false,"cancelUrl":"https://www.example.com/"}');
```

... the "cancel" button redirects the iframe to "example.com", which is not what I want. I want my *parent page* to redirect (or take some other action).

What am I doing wrong?

For reference:
Here are some instructions for setting up [Accept Hosted](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sample-app/blob/master/README-AcceptHosted.md).
Here is the recommended method of [prompting the checkout form](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sample-app/blob/master/getHostedPaymentForm.php).
Here is the recommended [iFrameCommunicator page](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sample-app/blob/master/iCommunicator.html).

This is essentially the same process I'm using, but the "cancel" button does nothing:
[How to implement Authorize.NET Hosted Payments iFrame & Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700622/how-to-implement-authorize-net-hosted-payments-iframe-laravel)

---

**EDIT:**

Note this description from the Authorize.net developer community forum. In my experience, this is not the way the "cancel" button works when the "cancelUrl" is provided. The URL loads inside the iframe, which is not desired.

> In an iframe scenario, a click on the "Cancel" button calls the "cancelContinueBtnHandler" function. That function will pass a message to you that the transaction has been cancelled, and if there is a "cancelUrl" that you passed, will then direct the browser to that URL. So, that URL doesn't load within the iframe, but within the browser.

-- [community.developer.authorize.net](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Accept-Hosted-Iframe-Cancel-Button/m-p/57298#U57302)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JavaScript code for handling the "cancel" button, nothing happens unless a return `url` or `cancelUrl` parameter is provided. And it looks like it redirects the iframe even if the event is passed back to the merchant, which I had not expected.

https://test.authorize.net/payment/scripts/app-min.js

```js
m.cancelContinueBtnHandler = function(w) {
  var v = (w === "continue" ? m.continueURL : m.cancelURL);
  if (v && g_iframeCommunicatorUrl.length > 0 && m.isIframeCommunication) {
    IFrameCommunication.sendCommunicationToMerchant("action=cancel");
    window.location = v
  } else {
    if (v) {
      window.location = v
    }
  }
};
```

So, I was misunderstanding the way this is intended to work. As others have mentioned, the current documentation is a bit spotty/misleading. Since the iframe redirects regardless, I'll consider it as a fallback for the JavaScript handler. Here's what I'm using now:

```php
$setting->setSettingName("hostedPaymentReturnOptions");
$setting->setSettingValue('{"showReceipt" : false, "url" : "https://www.example.com/return/", "cancelUrl" : "https://www.example.com/cancel/" }');
```

I will also look into using [WebHooks](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/webhooks.html) as a more reliable way of recording successful payments.